add-app-repository fails due to connection problem (13: permission denied)
I am using the latest release version of Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS and tried to update my libre office to the latest version by adding the update information to the repository with "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa".
But each time the execution of this command is interrupted and I get displayed the following connection error:
Failed to fetch https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease
Could not connect to ppa.launchpadcontent.net:443 (2620:2d:4000:1::81). - connect (13: Permission denied)
Could not connect to ppa.launchpadcontent.net:443 (185.125.190.80). - connect (113: No route to host)

A few weeks ago I tried to add a repository for my "DB Browser for SQlite". Unfortunately it failed due to the same reasons (Permission denied, No route to host).
I already checked the sources list with lsattr /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ to check if the repository-path is marked as immutable, but it isn't.
I changed the nameserver in resolv.conf to a public dns server, but that does not solve my problem.
My (personal) system is connected via lan and uses a portmaster firewall. But I don't get any prompt notification when the add-apt-repository command is interrupted.  sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade works without any problems. But adding any repository with a https connection fails. I did not find the solution for my problem in the www and would be pleased for any hint.
